rsyslog imfile module, keep creating new log file
module(load="imfile" PollingInterval="10")
 input(type="imfile"
 tag="existing"
 File="/remotelogs//.log"
 Severity="info"
 Facility="local0")
it creates a log file, /remotelogs/existing.log, and has an error showing  imfile:'/remotelogs/existing.log' is FILE but DIRECTORY expected - ignored [v8.2112.0]
my goal is to ingest some log files under different ip folder within remotelogs to elk server. i am not sure using imfile can do it or not.it also need to send the new logs to elk server. I am new to rsyslog and elk server.
